# Wordpress pass parameter into url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I need something like this `example.com/postname/id/2`

I know that I can use `example.com/postname?id=2` , but first example url is more friendly.

Is this possible do with `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Your question is unclear according to your comments on answer below - Rework it. What you want to achieve can be done by changing `Permalink` Structure from settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the admin panel:

Options > Permalinks > Common options > Choose the one you want

Answer (score 2):

Anything in that format will end up causing complications with if not outright breaking the Wordpress pretty permalinks.  You would probably need to add a bunch of regex rewrite rules to htaccess as well.  Why not use a hash or query based url `#` or `?` followed by the parameter(s)?

Comment: How to use `#` ? `example.com/postname?id=2` in this example I want pass variable 2

Comment: using `document.window.hash` in javascript you can get the value of the url after the `#` symbol, although you will probably need to account for or cancel the default behavior (e.g. positioning viewport at element with id corresponding to #parameter).  But for example you could parse the `document.window.hash` and use that to set up an AJAX call to load the content you want, etc after parsing the parameter from the hash string.  It's kind of an odd way to do it but it's a possible alternative to using `?`. Note that htaccess rewrite rules may interfere with this based on your settings

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than you think. Take a loot at [WordPress Codex about how to use Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks). It's pretty easy to achieve what you want.

Comment: You not uderstand me, I need pass parameter into url from 1 page to second.

Comment: @TomasLietuva than you need to rework your question